# Python guessing game with clues

Tags: python

A Python(3.7) beginner here. This guessing game gives range clues:

- `Cold`
- `Warm`
- `Hot`

Depending on how close to answer player is.

Problem: how to add extra 3 incremental clues:

- `Colder`
- `Warmer`
- `Hotter`

  `Colder` is used if the next guess is further from answer.
  `Warmer` is used if the next guess is closer to answer.
  `Hotter` is used instead of `Warmer` if its in the `Hot` range.

The first guess produces the range clues `Cold`, `Warm` or `Hot`.

The subsequent guesses will produce incremetal clues `Colder` or `Warmer`/`Hotter` **if** while they land in same range as previous guess.

If they fall out of the range, the range clues `Cold`, `Warm` or `Hot` will be produced first  and **then** `Colder` or `Warmer`/`Hotter` while in that range. in other words `Cold`, `Warm` or `Hot` range clues have higher priority than incremental `Colder` or `Warmer`/`Hotter`.

```
print("The secret number is somewhere between 0 and 100. You have 5 guesses.")
user_input = int(input('Make a guess '))

count = 0

while user_input is not 41 and count < 4:
    count = count + 1
    how_close_to_answer = 41 - user_input
    if 5 < how_close_to_answer.__abs__() < 20:
        user_input = int(input(f'Warm. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))
    elif how_close_to_answer.__abs__() >= 20:
        user_input = int(input(f'Cold. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))
    else:
        user_input = int(input(f'Hot. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))


if user_input is not 41:
    print('You Lose!')
else:
    print('You Win!')
    print(f"It took you {count + 1} guesses to get this correct.")
```

For example (in case of infinite guesses n):

1. player guesses = 10 , desired outcome '`Cold`. Remaining guesses (n-1) '
2. next guess     = 15 , desired outcome '`Warmer`. Remaining guesses (n-2) '
3. next guess     = 12 , desired outcome '`Colder`. Remaining guesses (n-3) '
4. next guess     = 36 , desired outcome '`Hot`. Remaining guesses (n-4) '
5. next guess     = 37 , desired outcome '`Hotter`. Remaining guesses (n-5) '
6. next guess     = 30 , desired outcome '`Warm`. Remaining guesses (n-6) '

In 4. example - number 36 is `Warmer` than previous 12, but it also falls in the `Hot` range so the `Hot` clue is given instead.

in 6. example - number 30 is `Colder` than previous 37, but it also falls in the `Warm` range so the `Warm` clue is given instead.

Comment: First thing would be to EXACTLY decide how you want these extra clues to work.  If I had to guess you want all guesses after your first one to say either `warmer`, `colder`, or `HOT`. If a player guesses a `HOT` guess and then gets the next one inside `HOT` range, should your code say `HOT` again or one of `warmer` / `colder`?

Comment: Adding to @Hoog suggestion, you might want to do it based on whether their guess goes towards or away form the answer. i.e then guess 35, then 40, "warmer", then 38, "colder". That way you're saying they're getting "warmer" if they go from 10 to 15 even if they are in the same band. You might then want to do it such that if they are within 10% of the answer it says "hot".

Comment: if a guess falls in 'Cold' range it would first say 'Cold' and 'Warmer'/ 'Colder' while its stays  in 'Cold' range. Same goes for 'Warm' range. For 'Hot' range the same, except 'Hotter'/'Colder' instead of 'Warmer'/'Colder' . i.e. 20 -> 'Cold', then 21 -> 'Warmer', then 25 -> 'Warm', then 24 -> 'Colder', then 44 -> 'Hot', then 43 -> 'Hotter', then 45 -> 'Colder', then 15 -> 'Cold'. Basically the name of  range would be declared first and then relative progess inside that range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest I could get to what you asked for. The comments on your original question are worth a read in my opinion but I think this does exactly what you asked for in the question.

```
print("The secret number is somewhere between 0 and 100. You have 5 guesses.")
user_input = int(input('Make a guess '))

count = 0
last_distance = -1
while user_input is not 41 and count < 4:
    count = count + 1
    how_close_to_answer = (41 - user_input)
    how_close_to_answer = how_close_to_answer.__abs__()
    if how_close_to_answer <= 5 and last_distance > 5:
        user_input = int(input(f'Hot. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))
    elif last_distance == -1:
        if 5 < how_close_to_answer < 20:
            user_input = int(input(f'Warm. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))
        elif how_close_to_answer >= 20:
            user_input = int(input(f'Cold. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))
        elif how_close_to_answer <= 5:
            user_input = int(input(f'Hot. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))
    else:
        if how_close_to_answer < last_distance:
            if how_close_to_answer <= 5:
                user_input = int(input(f'Hotter. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))
            else:
                user_input = int(input(f'Warmer. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))
        elif how_close_to_answer > last_distance:
            user_input = int(input(f'Colder. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))
    last_distance = how_close_to_answer


if user_input is not 41:
    print('You Lose!')
else:
    print('You Win!')
    print(f"It took you {count + 1} guesses to get this correct.")
```

Hope this is what helps

Comment: Thanks, this is almost perfect solution. There are 2 issues:

Comment: 1st - when input is in 'hot' range, it stops tracking if the next guess is 'warmer' or 'colder'. 2nd: if the same number is input twice in a row (from 1 to 35 and from 47 to 100) the loop breaks prematurely with 'You lose message'  Sorry for double post - accidentaly pressed ender while typing

Comment: what do you want to happen if they enter the same number, you haven't specified. Also, not sure what the first issue is after reading your original question. Warmer / Colder still works even after an input is in hot range (e.g. guess 1 = 40 (output = Hot) guess 2 = 12 (output = Colder). What is desired?

Comment: Is this what you want?  Guess 1 = 39 (output = Hot), Guess 2 = 40 (output = Hotter)  If that is the case, what if the order of the guesses were reversed? Is it still just "Colder" (ahh, just saw your other reply. Seems like the only difference is you want the hotter functionality. Editing now)

Comment: Thanks, this solves everything. The other problem was pretty minor -   if player entered same number twice in a row, loop would break with 'You lose!' message  before remaining guesses were used. Fixed it by adding `else:
            user_input = int(input(f'Same. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))` between 26th and 27th line, to adress the case when how_close_to_answer = last_distance

Answer (score 1):

I took `num` as a random generated number instead of `41`.

```
import random 

print("The secret number is somewhere between 0 and 100. You have 5 guesses.")
user_input = int(input('Make a guess '))

count = 0
num = random.randint(1,101)

while user_input is not num and count < 4:
    #uncomment the line below to see random generated number
    #print('Generated Random Number= '+str(num))
    count = count + 1
    how_close_to_answer = num - user_input

    if abs(how_close_to_answer)>5 and abs(how_close_to_answer) <20 :
        user_input = int(input(f'Warm. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))
    elif abs(how_close_to_answer) >= 20 :
        user_input = int(input(f'Cold. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))
    else:
        user_input = int(input(f'Hot. Remaining guesses {5 - count} '))


if user_input is not num:
    print('You Lose!')
else:
    print('You Win!')
    print(f"It took you {count + 1} guesses to get this correct.")
```

As far as i understood , the above program generates a random number and you need to guess that number ,

- if your guessed number is less then or equivalent to  `5` digits closer to that random number it will tell you `hot`
- if its greater than `5` and less than `20` then it will tell you `warm`
- on greater than `20` it will give you `cold`

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: This changes 41 to a random number, but doesnt add 2 new clues 'Colder or 'Warmer'. if a guess falls in 'Cold' range it would first say 'Cold' and 'Warmer'/ 'Colder' while its stays in 'Cold' range. Same goes for 'Warm' range. For 'Hot' range the same, except 'Hotter'/'Colder' instead of 'Warmer'/'Colder' . i.e. 20 -> 'Cold', then 21 -> 'Warmer', then 25 -> 'Warm', then 24 -> 'Colder', then 44 -> 'Hot', then 43 -> 'Hotter', then 45 -> 'Colder', then 15 -> 'Cold'. Basically the name of range would be declared first and then relative progess inside that range.